# Create a plugin to change the action to which a function is hooked

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions

I have a plugin that hooks a function on to the `woocommerce_before_my_account` action.  I would like instead for the plugin to hook that function to the `woocommerce_after_my_account` action.

If I create my own plugin, is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) function to unhook a function from an action and then [`add_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to hook it elsewhere. Note that when removing an action you must specify the tag (hook name), function, and priority exactly as it was added.

**Edit: Here are some additional details:**

You'll have to look at the source of the other plugin to determine how to do that. Without specific information about which plugin and function you're talking about we can't give you an exact answer, but here's an example:

if the plugin hooks the function like this:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'function_to_move', 10 );`

you would do something like:

```
function my_move_woo_functions() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'function_to_move', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', 'function_to_move', 10 );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_move_woo_functions' );
```

The important part is that you have to move the action after their hook is created but before the hook is run.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the functions, but as the function that I need to hook to the woocommerce_after_my_account action is in another plugin, I don't know how I can access it.  i.e. how do I say "get this function from this plugin and hook it to this action"?

Comment: Additional details added to my additional response.

Comment: Just to underline @ScottNelle 's clear answer, it doesn't matter where in your plugins, theme or even core that the replacement function is defined, as long as it is defined somewhere.